# Using a While loop and Between operator for query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, between

I'd like to know if there is a better way to write this query or if how I am doing it is the most efficient.

I am lopping through a list of IP Addresses that I have already converted to their numeric value in its table. I then need to look up the Geo-location  data (from [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com) GeoIp2) where the selected IP Address is between the start and end IPs of the Geo-location data. Once I get the Geo-location data I update the the AllIP table with the Geo-location table's Id. This will allow me to inner join the tables later.

You will notice I am selecting the Id of the IP address inside the while loop so I can update the record by Id. This is because we may have multiple IP Addresses with the same value. Since I am looping through all the records I did not want to update by the numerical IP address value.

```
declare @ipcount int
declare @currentCount int
declare @ipAddress bigint
declare @id int
declare @geoCode int
set @currentCount = 0
set @ipcount = (select count(*) from AllIP where Processed = 0)

while @currentCount <=@ipcount
   BEGIN
     set @id = (select top 1 Id from AllIP where Processed = 0)
     set @ipAddress = (select IpAddressNumeric from AllIP where Id = @id)
     set @geoCode  = (
                     SELECT dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Locations].geoname_id
                      FROM
                     dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Blocks2]
                     INNER JOIN dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Locations] ON dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Blocks2].geoname_id = dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Locations].geoname_id
                     Where @ipAddress between dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Blocks2].startIp and dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Blocks2].endIp)

     update AllIP set Processed = 1,geocodeId = @geoCode where Id = @id
     set @currentCount = @currentCount+1
    end
```

Comment: You have an error `set @ipcount = (select count(*) from AllIP)` will select all records you want to iterate only over `AllIP where Processed = 0`

Comment: So you like doing more work than you have to? Every time you look up a particular IP address, you're going to get the same answer - but rather than use that answer for every instance of that IP address, you're going to just apply it to one row and then force yourself to do another lookup later?

Comment: @LIUFA, true, but the data is initially set to 0. I'll change the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the entire thing can be replaced by a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE a
SET Processed = 1, geoCodeId = gcb.geoname_id
FROM
    AllIp a
       inner join
    dbo.[GeoLite2-City-Blocks2] gcb
       on
          a.IpAddressNumeric between gcb.startIp and gcb.endIp
WHERE
    a.Processed = 0
```

(I've excluded the join to `GeoLite2-City-Locations` at the moment since the join column you're using is the same as the column that's being selected)

In general, you should prefer to write set-based code that deals with *all* rows to be updated in a single statement, rather than working row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR).

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could inner join using a between operator. sweet

Comment: @DDiVita - In general, if you can put it in a `WHERE` clause, you can put it in an `ON` clause for a `JOIN`.